What is Flex Domain,Application Domain and Real Time domain in iMX SoC
I was looking into the iMX series processor information. i.MX93 and i.MX94 specifically.
I can see that the processor blocks are divided into 3.They are as follows.

Flex Domain
Application Domain
Real Time Domain

May I know what are the difference between these 3 domains.

The graphic associated with this details the differences - application domain is the code that runs on the cortex A processor, real time on the Cortex M and flex on the npu/gpu.

Why they are running 3 different processors

Three different processors for three different workloads. You would normally run Linux on the cortex A processor - this might be a user interface or suchlike that requires plenty of processing and memory but not anything that requires strict timing constraints. For tasks that require strict timing, the cortex M processor is used - eg: fuel injection for a petrol engine. The flex processor is geared for matrix and AI workloads.
